# orientable manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be an orientable manifold and let $f:M \to R$ be a smooth map. Show that if $0$ is a
regular value of $f$ then  ${f^{ - 1}}(0) \subseteq M$ is also an orientable manifold.

Answer (score 5):

1. The preimage $K$ is a manifold by the implicit function theorem. (Alternatively: this is one case of Lemma 4 in Milnor's "Topology from the differentiable viewpoint.")
2. The gradient of $f$ is nonzero at every point of $K$ (because $0$ is a regular value). You can put an orientation on $K$ by saying that a frame $v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}$ is "positively oriented" in $K$ iff $v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}, \nabla f$ is positively oriented in $M$.

Comment: Why does $0$ being a regular value imply that the gradient of $f$ is nonzero at every point of $K$?

Comment: Every point of $K$ is in the preimage of $0$, i.e., for $x \in K$, we have $f(x) = 0$. Now $0$ is a regular value, so the derivative at $x$ must have maximal rank. In this case, that rank is 1, and the derivative is the gradient. Hence the gradient must span a vector space of dimension 1, so it cannot be zero.